# Python multiprocessing & pathos: import error

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-import, pathos

I am writing some python code using multiprocessing & pathos. I have written a small test program to get used to using the mutiprocessing, that runs fine on my local machine, but it refuses to run on a different cluster.

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./multi.py", line 116, in <module>
    pool = pathos_multiprocessing.Pool(processes=pool_size,maxtasksperchild=1,)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 150, in __init__
    self._setup_queues()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 243, in _setup_queues
    self._inqueue = self._ctx.SimpleQueue()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/multiprocess/context.py", line 110, in SimpleQueue
    from .queues import SimpleQueue
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/multiprocess/queues.py", line 22, in <module>
    import _multiprocess as _multiprocessing
ImportError: No module named '_multiprocess'
```

but when I do a

```
pip3 list
```

both pathos and multiprocessing modules are clearly there:

```
multiprocess (0.70.4)
nbconvert (4.2.0)
nbformat (4.0.1)
nose (1.3.1)
notebook (4.2.0)
numpy (1.10.4)
oauthlib (0.6.1)
pathos (0.2.0)
```

Any bright ideas why this might be happening would be welcome!

The small test code is:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import pathos.multiprocessing as mp
import os
import random

class Pool_set:
    def pool_fun(directory_name):
        cwd=os.getcwd()
        os.mkdir(str(directory_name))
        directory=os.path.join(cwd,str(directory_name))
        os.chdir(directory)
        os.system('{}'.format('sleep '+str(directory_name)))
        cwd2=os.getcwd()
        print(cwd2)
        test_file = open('test_file.out','w')
        test_file.write(cwd2)
        print("Finished in "+directory)
        os.chdir(cwd)

if __name__ == '__main__':


    config=[]
    pool_set = Pool_set
    for i in (random.sample(range(1,100),3)):
        config.append(i)

    pool_size = mp.cpu_count()
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=pool_size,maxtasksperchild=1,)

    pool_outputs = pool.map(pool_set.pool_fun,config)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: I can run your program without problem. Could you show the command you type and the full stacktrace?

Comment: Hey laike9m, full traceback included. The script is executable, and I just run it as ./multi.py. Thanks

Comment: I can't think of why. Have you tried running `python3 multi.py`?

Comment: Same problem with `python3 multi.py`, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

I'm the `pathos` and `multiprocess` author.  I think there are two possible reasons you can't find `_multiprocess`. The first, and by far most common reason, is that you don't have a C++ compiler.  `multiprocessing` needs a C++ complier, and if you are on Windows, you have to instal one. See: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers. The second is that it could not be found due to a `PATH`/`PYTHONPATH` issue with how it was installed if you mess with `prefix` etc, but that's the far minority case.